# Need a fix... The attribute 'width' may not appear in tag 'col' for AMP HTML

Tags: amp-html

Getting errors from Google Webmaster Tools on 86 pages that have tables of results (data).  Need an easy way to maintain AMP compliance while still displaying the results on a webpage.  One example page is http://www.dodgecountyfairgrounds.com/2014/08/19/junior-fair-poultry-judging-results-2/amp/

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error states the problem itself. `The attribute 'width' is not to be used inside the tag 'col'`. This is one of the so called [disallowed attributes](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/validation_errors#disallowed-attribute) from the AMP docs:

> **Disallowed attribute**
>
> *Code*: DISALLOWED_ATTR
>
> *Format*: "The attribute '%1' may not appear in tag '%2'."
>
> *Fix*: Remove the attribute from the HTML tag.
>
> Attributes are
> whitelisted, so there is no definitive list of all disallowed
> attributes. To check the supported attributes for each specific tag,
> search for HTML tag, and then attrs in the [AMP validator
> spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/validator/validator-main.protoascii).
>
> In addition to a whitelist of specific attributes for each tag, all
> AMP tags can use any of the attributes white-listed under
> $GLOBAL_ATTRS; all attributes with a prefix of "data-" are also
> whitelisted.

Comment: Going back to manually modify each post so it's AMP compliant